# Debugging JSBin with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, jsbin

I have problem with debugging js code written in js bin with chrome.

Everytime when i edit/click run with JS new source file is generated and old breakpoint are not being hit.

Do you have any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just use a `debugger` statement in your code. Even though jsbin will give you a warning and won't autorun, you can still click the `run` button (or press <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⏎</kbd>) and your code will pause on the `debugger` statement.

Comment: also, don't write JavaScript code in html, write JavaScript code in separate JavaScript editor.

Answer (score 2):

You can also look on the `Sources` tab for an item called `(no domain)`. The file inside it has your JS and you can set ***breakpoints***.

[image]

Comment: this seems to no longer be correct...I don't see any '(no domain)' item. Does anyone have an update?

Answer (score 0):

It is under  runner - JS Bin Output - (no domain) - leduzidigo.js

[image]